# QLPreviewController fail to load video files

Tags: ios, video, qlpreviewcontroller

I am facing some issue while trying to open video file on QLPreviewcontroller.
While trying to open video file , i just see a thumbnail of video file loaded & dont see any playback controls or any controls.
 Neither video seems playing nor any audio sound.
I am adding previewcontroller view as subview to a view.
Any thoughts on what could be issue?

Comment: I have the same problem. Any ideas yet?

Comment: In my case the controls were offscreen for some reason. I had to move the view up.

Comment: same problem here, did u solve it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475957/objective-c-qlpreviewcontroller-does-not-display-image?noredirect=1#comment81911108_47475957